# Why do North Americans pronounce "caramel" as "carmel"?

Tags: pronunciation, north-american-english

"Caramel", which (clearly) has an "a" in the middle, has only this spelling world wide.

But in my experience, North Americans (Canadians too) don't pronounce the middle "a". They pronounce it exactly like the girl's name Carmel. From my experience, *all* Americans pronounce it without the "a" and *all* other places pronounce it with the middle "a" voiced.

Why is that?

Can this difference in pronunciation be traced to a root cause?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; they are to seek clarification of the post. This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53271/discussion-on-question-by-bohemian-why-do-americans-pronounce-caramel-as-carm). The many, many offtopic comments posted after the first few dozen were moved to chat have all been deleted. Any others like them will be deleted on sight. Worse, some were borderline offensive in violation of our Be Nice policy. Please direct all further comments to chat, but keep it civil this time. Flag offensive comments.

Comment: I have to say that (as a Brit) if I heard someone say 'carmel' I would immediately think of **[Mount Carmel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Carmel)**.  I certainly wouldn't understand it as a different pronunciation of *caramel* - I wasn't aware that it is pronounced differently in much of the US.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Do you say car-a-mel or car-mel? Is your “fire” closer to fah-yer or fayr?

{[Arika Okrent _ Mentalfloss.com _ 3 reasons for syllabically ambiguous words](http://mentalfloss.com/article/53661/car-mel-or-car-mel-3-reasons-syllabically-ambiguous-words)}

> - There is a group of words in English that can be pronounced with two different syllable structures, depending on dialect, personal preference, or context of use. ***While many will insist that one or the other is incontrovertibly correct, there is usually no real basis for pronouncements on the one true syllable structure***. Sometimes two things can both be correct. If you need a better authority than me on that, lots of dictionaries accept both pronunciations for all the words discussed below (e.g., Merriam-Webster). What’s more interesting than fighting about who’s right is understanding why these differences arise. There are three processes that result in syllabically ambiguous words.

***Two or Three Syllables***: *caramel, mayonnaise, family, chocolate, camera, different, separate, favorite*:

> - ***These words all have a syllable which is often left out of the pronunciation.***   When we cut a sound out of the middle of a word, it’s called syncope (a three syllable word, sin-ko-pee). O-range becomes ornge, ***car-a-mel becomes car-mel***, in-ter-es-ting becomes in-tres-ting. This pruning of syllables doesn’t happen in some random, haphazard fashion. If a vowel gets chucked, it will be before an r or l (those guys again!) or in some cases a nasal (m or n). ***It will also be from an unstressed syllable. So the American LA-buh-ra-to-ry becomes lab-ra-to-ry, while the British la-BO-ra-to-ry become la-bo-ra-try.***

(mentalfloss.com)

[Caramel](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/06/9-pronunciation-arguments-you-can-stop-having/) appears have different pronunciations in different English dialects, the AmE one is just a variant which has been in place for a long time:

> - The word caramel can acceptably be pronounced in several accepted ways, including KARR-uh-mel, KARR-uh-muhl, and, ***in North American English, KAR-muhl. The disappearance of that second syllable -uh- in the final pronunciation seems to have been in the works for a long time***. The word has been in English since the 18th century, which it came via French from the Spanish caramel. Order that caramel ice cream sundae however you like!

(blog.oxforddictionaries.com)

[image] From (www.listenandlearnusa.com/blog)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Why? What is the root cause?" except by implication that "no-one knows". What **caused** the North American syllable to be universally dropped, while that didn't happen anywhere else?

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: ... Nevertheless, far from irrelevant to the subject and a very good find.

Comment: @josh firstly, that map is awesome! If I were to guess, I would say that 2 syllables came into vogue first half of last century. Is there a reference to a timeline or popular cooking radio show or something? It had to start somewhere.

Comment: @Bohemian - Unluckily not, hard to find I guess: https://www.listenandlearnusa.com/blog/pronunciation-maps-usa/

Comment: Intriguingly, Katz's original had 'I use both forms,  but the two have different meanings' rather than 'other'. Any ideas?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/caramel) has three meanings for caramel: a sweet liquid, a hard candy and a colour. It's not impossible that someone might use two syllables for food and three syllables for the colour, for example.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm from an ostensibly red part of the country, and I say both. Two syllables is used attributively, three is for a piece of candy. Possibly it's related to stress patterns?

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Actually, I think it does.Look at that map again, and recall that the USA expanded from Atlantic coastal communities westward. This map makes it pretty clear whose dialect "won"  most of the interior. (I knew there was a reason I always liked Philly).

Comment: @T.E.D. That map wasn't there when I added my comment. But although it might *possibly* show when the change happened (as the march westwards has presumably been documented), none of this answer shows why a syllable was spontaneously dropped, except if it's "It happens. That *-a-* was too much trouble and it didn't mean anything anyway." -- which is a reason which would not have occurred in the rest of the world.

Comment: It may not show why that exact pronunciation happened in the first place to the first person who started doing it (that's almost certainly unanswerable), but it does show why its so prevalent in the US. I think its a reasonable presumption that this question was asking the answerable "why" question, rather than the unanswerable one.

Comment: The phenomenon is "syncope" which is not restricted to AmE. Not sure why the answer needs to address "carmel" specifically. Probably beyond that it just comes down to an ease-of-use choice. I am wondering if it is related to the way that randomized letters in the middle of a word have little impact on reading comprehension.

Comment: From Michigan, can confirm.

Comment: Why is there no mention of the vowel shift?  "car-ml" is [kɑɹ.mel] while "carra-mel" is [kɛəɹ.ə.mel]

Comment: Another from ostensibly red part of the map, who pronounces it car-a-mel, and has never heard of a girl being named 'Carmel' - that's a city in California, more formally known as Carmel-by-the-Sea :-)

Comment: I need to start calling it a lab-ra-try now.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not a phonetician. I probably wouldn't be able to hear the difference between /ɛər/ and /er/ very well even if I found audio clips of them. Instead, here's a paper: http://udel.edu/~parrell/pdfs/Riera_2009.pdf It makes three relevant points: 1. various authors have used transcriptions like /ɛər/ for the phoneme in AmEng "hair" 2. phonetically, a schwa-like vowel may be present in Vr sequences in AmEng, but it is quite variable 3. the thesis of the paper is that this is coarticulatory, not phonemic, so it does argue against transcriptions involving the symbol ə.

Comment: @tchrist: My take on that would be: /er/ or /ɛr/ is preferable to /ɛər/, but the latter isn't wrong enough to have to be corrected. I think I hear a diphthong in the following pronunciations of "lair": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzGVJF8o0rc&feature=youtu.be&t=37m10s, https://youtu.be/iZ3gKVr9taE?t=3m25s

Comment: That heat map, which was by a student rather than the researchers who collected the data (Bert Vaux and Marius L. Jøhndal), obscures a LOT of detail. The original map is [here](http://www.tekstlab.uio.no/cambridge_survey/maps/244), showing a much more complex situation: *with 2 syllables ("car-ml") (41%)   with 3 syllables ("carra-mel") (33%)   **I use both interchangeably (18%)   I have both forms, but the two have different meanings (please state how in the comments box) (3%)   other (2%)***

Comment: @AndrewLeach many questions here ask 'why' but they often are impossible to answer like that. All you can really do is describe more explicitly what the phenomenon _is_. What could a reason for this particular change possibly be beyond a generic '[syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology)) is common'?

Comment: @sumelic Oh interesting! You’re completely right: Wil does have a pronunciation that's almost disyllabic, well on its way to *layer*.  I’m not sure how best to represent that. It makes me wonder whether his [*payer* and his *pear* are homophones, too, or his *mayor* and his *mare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Mare.E2.80.93mayor_merger). Needless to say, I don’t have the merger. I think their example of [ˈmeəneɪz] I would write as [ˈmeɪəneɪz] or maybe even [ˈmeɪjəneɪz] — because I perceive a glide there just as I do in all [eə] examples, to me [ejə]

Comment: @tchrist - Not sure who "Wil" is (deleted comment?), but I know for me personally mayor and mare are homonyms (as are about half the words in the table you linked), and the difference between payer and pear is extraordinarily subtle (mostly a difference in # of syllables).

Answer (score 11):

Americans don't all use "carmel". Many of them think it's more correct to say "carr-a-mel", so you can find a number of examples of this pronunciation being used, especially in formal contexts. Go through some of the [Youglish](http://youglish.com/search/caramel/us) US pronunciations of "caramel".

There is a word where a similar syncopated pronunciation is, as far as I know, universal for American English speakers: *[squirrel](http://youglish.com/search/squirrel/us)*.

Phonetically, *squirrel* may actually be one syllable or two, probably in part due to uncertain syllabification of word-final /l/ after /r/. But the identity of the rhotic vowel (/ɜr/ as in "fur" rather than /ɪr/ as in "mirror") suggests that this word may have been underlyingly compressed to one syllable in the historical ancestor of the pronunciation that modern American English speakers use. (I'm not certain that the change in vowel quality is related to syllable structure, since "syrup" also shows a variant pronunciation with /ɜr/ in American English.)

I don't know of any other examples besides these two, though. (Unless you count *iron* = *iern,* which occurs also in British English, and the less common *irony* = *ierny*.)

I don't know what caused these pronunciations to be established only in North America. It seems possible that the presence of rhotic vowels somehow contributed; in most British accents it would be impossible to have "r" in disyllabic /kɑrməl/ or monosyllabic /sqɜrl/, since "r" at the end of syllables has been converted to mere alteration of the length or quality of the preceding vowel (the pronunciations would instead be /kɑːməl/ and /sqɜːl/; compare *Mount Carmel* /maʊnt kɑːməl/ and *pearl* /pɜːl/).

Comment: Here is historical video evidence that we Americans do indeed argue over the pronunciation of "caramel." [It's that Shaq commercial for Nestle Crunch Bars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Z2-ZCBCHWI)

Comment: @sumelic In all British accents, whether rhotic or not, the /r/ in "caramel" and "squirrel" is pronounced because it comes before a vowel. As you point out, however, dropping /r/+<vowel> in non-rhotic accents would result in pronunciations like "camel" (as British English uses /æ/ in the first syllable of "caramel") and "squill".

Comment: See, I always thought it was because of venues where you have people shouting out their wares. "CAR-mel APP-ells" has a different rhythm than "CAR-a-mel" APP-ells" when shouting over a crowd.

Comment: British people can pronounce the /r/ in *referral*. They could easily pronounce *squerral* to rhyme with it; they just don't.

Comment: I think what’s happening with *caramel* is the same things happening with *caravel*, *caravan*, *carousel*, and also with *carmelized*. It’s twofold. One part is ①  tense–lax neutralization before ‹r› for most North Americans. But another part is ②  the front–back distinction because although we can have a back vowel there, they never can; they **always** have a front vowel there. So *caramel* is UK [ˈkʰaɹəməl], [ˈkʰæɹəməl], [ˈkʰæɹəmɛl] but US [ˈkʰɛɹəˌmɛl], [ˈkʰɑɹməl]; *caravel* is UK [ˈkʰaɹəvɛl], [ˈkʰæɹəvɛl] but US [ˈkʰɛɹəˌvɛl]; *caravan* is UK [ˈkʰæɹəˌvan], [ˈkʰaɹəˌvan] but US [ˈkʰɛɹəˌvæn].

Comment: And *caramelized* is UK [ˈkʰaɹəməlʌɪzd], [ˈkʰæɹəml̩ʌɪzd], [ˈkʰæɹməˌlaɪzd] but US [ˈkʰɛɹməˌlɐɪzd], [ˈkʰɑɹm̩l̩ɐɪzd]. The reason that *caramelized* is more complicated because of the possibility of syllabic consonants falling one way or another depending on which syllable’s schwa disappears to create it.